# How to extract average star rating from this amazon template?(python, web scraping)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How can I extract the average rating(4.0 out of 5 stars) information from this amazon template ([https://www.amazon.com/Windsor-Glider-Ottoman-White-Cushion/dp/B017XRDV5S/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1520265105&sr=1-1&keywords=-gggg&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017XRDV5S)) in csv. This information is below the title in the left. I think this is a dynamic information that uses javascript(to make this average of stars). I attached the code. I appreciate any help.

```html
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html
import sys

links = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/Windsor-Glider-Ottoman-White-Cushion/dp/B017XRDV5S/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1520265105&sr=1-1&keywords=-gggg&th=1'
]
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://218.50.2.102:8080',
    'https': 'http://185.93.3.123:8080'
}

def get_information(driver,urls):
    with open('csv/sort_products.csv', "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        writer.writerow(['Review' ,'Link'])
        for url in urls:
            driver.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
            try:
                review = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="averageCustomerReviews"]/span/span/span/a').text
            except:
                review='No review'
                print('No review')
        
            writer.writerow([review,url])
            print(f'{url}\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="%s"' % ';'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in proxies.items()]))

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei-PC\Downloads\webdriver\chromedriver.exe",
                              chrome_options=chrome_options)
    get_information(driver,links)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below

```
stars = driver.find_element_by_id('acrPopover').get_attribute('title')
```

Comment: Can you help me please with this template (https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A1063306%2Ck%3Aas&keywords=as&ie=UTF8&qid=1532070774). The same problem. How can I get the reviews average? This template doesn't have attribute for title to use the same method. Can you help me please with this template? Thank you.

Comment: I put the question on stackoverflow with this title (How to get a dynamic information from an Amazon products page(average review)?(web scraping))

Comment: `stars = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-icon-alt').text`